# git via vpn не работает

Tags: git, vpn

Приветствую! Задавал сегодня вопрос уже по этой теме, где мне сказали однозначно настраивать vpn и дальше пробовать через него. Так вот, впн настроил. ip видно что другой, виртуальный сетевой адаптер работает, в общем все ок, вроде бы. Но при клонировании репы возникает такая ошибка

```
fatal: unable to connect to 192.168.1.8:
192.168.1.8[0: 192.168.1.8]: errno=Invalid argument
```

В чем может быть проблема?
P.S. пытаюсь рабочий проект клонировать на домашний ноут.

Comment: Клонируете через git-протокол или по https?

Comment: Выдает такую ошибку: fatal: unable to access 'https://192.168.1.8/myproject/': Can't       complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0. (1)

Comment: Если не сложно дополните ответ полной командой git clone, как она у вас сейчас выглядит?

Comment: git clone https: / /192.168.1.8/myproject пробелов между слешами нету, а то так не отображается нормально.

Comment: А адрес 192.168.1.8 пингуется? До него есть доступ?

Comment: Не подскажите, какие были стандартные порты у http.proxy и https.proxy? Видимо, когда еще и с тором шаманил, там все сбил. Когда тор выключен выдается такая ошибка fatal: unable to access 'https://192.168.1.8/myproject/': Failed to connect to localhost port 9150: Connection refused

Comment: На работе все хорошо пингуется. Те, кто линуксе сидят, юзают впн для работы с гитом. Я так же спросил, можно ли на домашний ноут проект стянуть, мне сказали: "Да, с помощью впн".

Comment: UPD.

почистил в .gitconfig настройки прокси, оставил только стандартные. В итоге под впн пытаясь клонировать репо под https, вылазит следующая ошибка:  Failed to connect to 192.168.1.8 port 443: Timed out
UPD2 И если что, комп на работе в домене. Может это как-то влияет

Comment: давайте конкретику. 192.168.1.8 - это чей ай-пи адрес?
Дополнительно хочу уточнить решилась ли проблема? Если да, то как?

Comment: @gecube решилась проблема. Путем выделения мне порта под rdp.